# How to declare a Map containing certain properties with flowtype & immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js, flowtype

Given a website object created like this

```
import {Map} from 'immutable' 
const website = new Map({name: 'My Website', url: 'http://www.myw.fr'})
```

How could I declare a websiteType which would be a map containing exactly the given properties.
I know I can do:

```
declare type websiteType = Map<string,string>
```

But I would like to be more specific, and declare a map that must contain the properties `name` and `url` of type `string`.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Hey, I'm actually looking for a similar answer. Have you found anything out?

Comment: Hello I haven't found a way to do it with flowtype. However there is the record type in immutablejs which allows you to achieve the same goal by declaring a constrained map with default values. Cf: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I got your question right, because I have never used a map from "immutable" therefore I will use an [es6 Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Why don't you just use a class?

```
class Website extends Map<string, string> {
    constructor(name: string, url: string) {
        super()
        this.set("name", name)
        this.set("url", url)
    }
}
```

That way you can initialize it like this:

```
const website = new Website("awesome", "www.awesome.com")
```

and then perform get and set operations.

If you miss the parameters flowtype will throw an error.

I hope this will be a solution for you.

> EDIT:

You could also just create a function which initializes your map.

```
declare type WebsiteType = Map<string, string>

function createWebsite(name: string, description: string) {
    const website: WebsiteType = new Map
    website.set("name", name)
    website.set("description", description)
    return website
}
```

However I find the first solution nicer because it gives you a Website type
and you don't have to create a creator function.

> EDIT:

If you want the same syntax like you used the map initialization,
you could also do:

```
class Website extends Map<string, string> {
    constructor({name, url, ...rest}) {
        super()
        this.set("name", name)
        this.set("url", url)
        for(const name in rest) {
            this.set(name, rest[name])
        }
    }
}
```

However I think the first one meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Map is the solution to this problem. You can restrict it using enums but this doesn't seem to solve the problem. Here are some results that I got while playing around:

```
type MyKeys = 'A' | 'B';
declare type MyMapType = Map<MyKeys, number>;

const TinyMap: MyMapType = Map({
  A: 1,
});
// As expected this doesn't give an error
console.log(TinyMap.get('B'));

const MyMap: MyMapType = Map({
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
});

// Just a 'number'
MyMap.get('A');

// Somewhat surprisingly this works fine
const NewMap = MyMap.set('A', 'a');

// Now of type 'number | string'
NewMap.get('A')

// Forcing the return into the type causes the error that one
// perhaps would expect: 'string This type is incompatible with number'
const AnotherMap: MyMapType = MyMap.set('A', 'a');
```